# Beamer - equation overlay breaking page layout

Tags: beamer, equations, overlays

I'm trying to include some overlays on a beamer slide with equations, but the result is different from the original without them.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}
\usefonttheme[only large]{structurebold}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Áreas de intercambio directo}
\begin{centering}%
  \framebox(100,60){}% Imagine there's an image instead
\par\end{centering}%

\begin{equation*}
\overline{s_{i}s_{j}}=\iint_{A_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}\cos\theta{}_{j}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}A_{j}
\end{equation*}

\onslide<2->
{
\begin{equation*}
\overline{s_{i}g_{j}}=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}K}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}V_{j}
\end{equation*}
}

\onslide<3->
{
\begin{equation*}
\overline{g_{i}g_{j}}=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iiint_{V_{i}}\frac{K^{2}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}V_{i}\text{d}V_{j}
\end{equation*}
}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get the following result, with that horrible extra vertical space:

[image]

If I remove the overlays it looks fine.

I've also tried with `\uncover`. Same result.

Comment: Try to remove the empty line between the `}` of the 2nd `\onslide` and 3rd `\onslide` statements

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That was the problem. Thanks so much. If you wish to post an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I think there are better solutions than my proposition. I suggest to use `\begin{align*}\onslide<...>{...}\onslide<...>{...}onslide<...>{...}\end{align*}, for example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Do you know why only the empty line between the 2nd and 3rd `\onslide` is causing the extra space, but not the empty line before the 2nd `\onslide`? I also tried enclosing the 1st equation into an `\onslide<1->` for symmetry reasons, but there's still only a space for the second empty line ...

Comment: @Wiebe: In short: No, I have no answer for this.

Comment: @Wiebke If you use `\onslide<1->{...}` the empty line between 1st and 2nd will also increase the spacing.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter: Which one: The first or the 2nd?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In my opinion the first (remove the empty line) answers the question, the second "use align*" could be a add-on, that's up to you :)

Comment: @samcarter: ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the empty line between the 2nd and the 3rd `\onslide<>` content.

In addition, I added a `\begin{align*}...\end{align*}` version for better alignment of equations with respect to the `=` symbol.

```
\documentclass[spanish,10pt]{beamer}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times}

\useoutertheme[height=0pt,width=3cm,left]{sidebar}
\usecolortheme{dove,sidebartab}
\usefonttheme[only large]{structurebold}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Áreas de intercambio directo}

\begin{centering}%
  \framebox(100,60){}% Imagine there's an image instead
\par\end{centering}%


\begin{equation*}
\overline{s_{i}s_{j}}=\iint_{A_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}\cos\theta{}_{j}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}A_{j}
\end{equation*}

\onslide<2->
{%
\begin{equation*}
\overline{s_{i}g_{j}}=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}K}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}V_{j}
\end{equation*}
}% Remove the empty line here
\onslide<3->
{%
\begin{equation*}
\overline{g_{i}g_{j}}=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iiint_{V_{i}}\frac{K^{2}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}V_{i}\text{d}V_{j}
\end{equation*}
}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Áreas de intercambio directo}
\begin{centering}%
  \framebox(100,60){}% Imagine there's an image instead
\par\end{centering}%

\begin{align*}
\overline{s_{i}s_{j}}&=\iint_{A_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}\cos\theta{}_{j}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}A_{j} \\
\onslide<2->{%
\overline{s_{i}g_{j}}&=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iint_{A_{i}}\frac{\cos\theta{}_{i}K}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}A_{i}\text{d}V_{j} \\
}
\onslide<3->{%
\overline{g_{i}g_{j}}&=\iiint_{V_{j}}\iiint_{V_{i}}\frac{K^{2}}{\pi r^{2}}\text{e}^{-Kr}\text{d}V_{i}\text{d}V_{j}} \\
\end{align*}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]